# SublimeText API - shifting the region position?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

This has been super annoying because it's the last thing that needs to be fixed before the Sublime plugin is ready.

An HSLa converter. The goal is to do this, example:

*Before:*

```
 color : #000;
```

*After (intended):*

```
 color: #000;
 color : hsla(...);
```

*But I get this:*

```
   color : hsla(...);
   color: #000;
```

Wrong order.

The routine:

- duplicate the original region.
- insert the converted hsla equivalent.

But it is referencing the original region position, so the inserted HSLa always ends up first. It needs to end up second since the HEX should come first as a CSS fallback.

I need to shift the region either down before inserting. Not clear from the Sublime API how to do this. Or if you have another solution?

Tnx, help appreciated.

----------- code --------

```
    for region in selection:
        if not region.empty():
            line = self.view.line(region)
            line_str = '\n' + self.view.substr(line) // HEX/RGB fallback
            self.view.insert(self.edit, line.end(), line_str)

            word = self.view.substr(region)
            css_hsl = convert_to_hsl(word,force_alpha) // HSLa equivalent
            if isinstance(css_hsl, str):
                self.view.replace(self.edit, region, css_hsl)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you are using. Otherwise, we have no idea what you're doing, and can't help you fix it.

Comment: Pertinent code added. Basically: 1) duplicate the existing HEX | RGB line as a fallback. 2) convert the HEX | RGB values in-situ to create the HSLa equivalent. Works great, just the output order is wrong.